# URl rewriting with more than two $_GET variables with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use url rewriting on my website page 
`http://example.com/subcategories.php?sub_category=1&location=Jaipur&sort=rating`

And I want to convert this to

```
http://example.com/{sub_category_name}.html
```

The listing on page is coming from other page using ajax

The code I used in .htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subcategories.php?subcat_name=$1&sub_category=$2&location=$3&sort=$4 [QSA]
```

But page is displaying as blank. Need help with the proper rewrite rule for this to work